# Python dictionary : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, hash, dictionary

I'm having troubles in populating a python dictionary starting from another dictionary.

Let's assume that the "source" dictionary has string as keys and has a list of custom objects per value.

I'm creating my target dictionary exactly as I have been creating my "source" dictionary how is it possible this is not working ?

I get

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Code :

```
aTargetDictionary = {}
for aKey in aSourceDictionary:
    aTargetDictionary[aKey] = []
    aTargetDictionary[aKey].extend(aSourceDictionary[aKey])
```

The error is on this line : `aTargetDictionary[aKey] = []`

Comment: works fine on my terminal. Give an example of **aSourceDictionary** which you are using

Comment: Downvoted this question since crucial aspects of the question are in dispute, and the OP has not addressed the disputes. This question annoyingly popped up in my Google search, presumably due to its high vote-count.

Answer (score 65):

The error you gave is due to the fact that in python, `dictionary keys` must be `immutable types` (if key can change, there will be problems), and list is a mutable type.

Your error says that you try to use a list as dictionary key, **you'll have to change your list into tuples** if you want to put them as keys in your dictionary.

According to [the python doc](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) :

> The only types of values not acceptable as keys are values containing
> lists or dictionaries or other mutable types that are compared by
> value rather than by object identity, the reason being that the
> efficient implementation of dictionaries requires a key’s hash value
> to remain constant

Comment: But in this example, the keys are string(as the questioner says)

Comment: @0xc0de : the code says something while the error says something else, I trust the error ;)

Comment: @0xc0de : we agree, all the answers are saying the same thing, the code displayed by OP works, but he still have an error, I just try to explain the cause of the error.

Comment: :true!
codeJack: Are you sure the keys are strings? your error says 'NO'!

Comment: @0xc0de in python strings are immutable: [ask Guido](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-are-python-strings-immutable)

Comment: Looks to me like the OP is using singleton lists of strings as keys in the new dictionary. Hence the need to convert the new keys to tuples.

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed rather odd.

If `aSourceDictionary` were a dictionary, I don't believe it is possible for your code to fail in the manner you describe.

This leads to two hypotheses:

1. The code you're actually running is not identical to the code in your question (perhaps an earlier or later version?)
2. `aSourceDictionary` is in fact not a dictionary, but is some other structure (for example, a list).

Answer (score 5):

As per your description, things don't add up. If `aSourceDictionary` is a dictionary, then your for loop has to work properly.

```
>>> source = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 3]}
>>> target = {}
>>> for key in source:
...   target[key] = []
...   target[key].extend(source[key])
... 
>>> target
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 3]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine : http://codepad.org/5KgO0b1G,
your `aSourceDictionary` variable may have other datatype than dict

```
aSourceDictionary = { 'abc' : [1,2,3] , 'ccd' : [4,5] }
aTargetDictionary = {}
for aKey in aSourceDictionary:
        aTargetDictionary[aKey] = []
        aTargetDictionary[aKey].extend(aSourceDictionary[aKey])
print aTargetDictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use defaultdict to address this situation. It goes something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

#initialises the dictionary with values as list
aTargetDictionary = defaultdict(list)

for aKey in aSourceDictionary:
    aTargetDictionary[aKey].append(aSourceDictionary[aKey])
```