# Unhashable Type: 'list'

Tags: python

I have a dict (IDMapping) that I'm looking up to in order to get a value, which I am then using to lookup to another dict (defaultFood).  I'm having trouble.

My code currently looks like this:

```
homePSDpath = os.curdir
foodName = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z_]+)\\food', homeFoodpath).group(1)
foodName = foodName.decode("utf-8")
myFoodKey = IDMapping.get(foodName)
print defaultFood.get(myFoodKey)
```

This results in:
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I have tried converting foodName to a tuple prior to using it to look up to the IDMapping, but this results in FALSE:

```
myFoodKey = tuple(myFoodKey)
```

I'm sure I'm doing something silly here.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python dictionary : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532146/python-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: what does `print(IDMapping.get(foodName))` output? A list of lists maybe?

Comment: print(IDMapping.get(foodName)) results in an output of [45]

Comment: what are the keys stored as in `defaultFood`?

Comment: defaultFood:
{0: [2, 3], 1: [3, 4], 2: [2, 3], 3: [1, 2], 45: [0, 1]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the element inside the list:

```
print defaultFood.get(myFoodKey[0])
```

i.e `IDMapping.get(foodName) -> [45]` so `[45][0] -> 45`

If you have a reverse mapping I would suggest storing the values of `IDMapping` as either tuples, ints or string depending on what you want to do with them and make the keys of `defaultFood` the same.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Ok, feeling a bit silly for that one.. haha!  Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries, use a tuple, int etc.. to make life easier

Answer (score 0):

It's because the values in IDMapping are lists. You cannot use a list as the key to a dictionary (as it's mutable). Hence, when you attempt to use a list in `defaultFood.get(myFoodKey)`, it throws the error that you're seeing (Unhashable type: list).

You need to come up with some way to convert myFoodKey from a list to a string or integer or some other non-mutable type.

ex:

```
myFoodKey = "".join([str(x) for x in myFoodKey])
```

would convert a list of objects into a list of strings and then join them together such that `[4, 5]` would become `"45"` which you can use as a key in a dictionary.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the help!