# Cannot apply method of finding unique rows in numpy.darray in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

I'm trying to choose only unique rows in numpy.ndarray (variable named **cluster**).
When I define this variable explicitely like here:

```
cluster=np.array([[0.157,-0.4778],[0.157,-0.4778],[0.157,-0.4778],[-0.06156924,-0.21786049],[-0.06156924,-0.21786049],[0.02,-0.35]])
```

it works as it should:

```
[[ 0.157      -0.4778    ]
 [-0.06156924 -0.21786049]
 [ 0.02       -0.35      ]]
```

But unfortunately this variable **cluster** is a part of a bigger array (*xtrans*). So it can be defined only through array slicing:

```
splitted_clusters=[0,1,4,5,10]
```

`cluster=xtrans[splitted_clusters]`

The functions are the same, the data types are the same.

BUT!!! in latter case it works quite weird: it may add identical rows or it may not add them. *As a result* I have something like this:

```
    [[ 0.157      -0.4778    ]
     [ 0.157      -0.4778    ]
     [-0.06156924 -0.21786049]
     [ 0.02       -0.35      ]]
```

In my *real example* with an 44*2 array it adds  22  identical rows and it misses 23 of them (the scheme is quite strange too: it adds rows with indices 0,1,2,4,9,11,12,18 etc). But the number of added identical rows differs. 
AND it is supposed to add only ONE (the first) row of these 44 rows.

As for method of choosing unique rows firstly I used one from this thread [Find unique rows in numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

```
b =np.ascontiguousarray(cluster).view(np.dtype((np.void, cluster.dtype.itemsize * cluster.shape[1])))
_, idx = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
unique_cl = cluster[idx]
```

Then I've tried my code to check:

```
unique_cl=np.array([0,0])
for i in range(cluster.shape[0]):
    if i==0:
        unique_cl=np.vstack([cluster[i,:]])
    elif cluster[i,:].tolist() not in unique_cl.tolist():
        unique_cl=np.vstack([unique_cl,cluster[i,:]])
```

The results are the same and I really have no idea why. 
I would be very grateful for any help/advice/suggestion/idea.

The problem was in floats. When I rounded values of array to 7 decimal places everything works as should. Thank  Eelco Hoogendoorn for this idea.

Comment: Is `b` the same?  It looks like `b` is the same data, but each row is viewed as a 16 bytes 'void' element.  That allows `unique` to do its flattened sort and selection.

Comment: @hpaulj I suppose yes, as there is no other `b` in this code. It's of type `'numpy.ndarray'` as well but when I try to print it I see strange symbols and I don't know how encode/decode them:
`[��|гY�? 9��v���? � h"lx�? @   ��|гY�? 9��v���?
 � h"lx�? ��|гY�? 9��v���? � h"lx�? �K7�A`�? 9��v���? F����x�? ��|гY�?
 9��v���? � h"lx�? @   ��|гY�? 9��v���? � h"lx�?
 ��|гY�? 9��v���? � h"lx�? @  @ @]`

Comment: What is the shape and dtype of the `b` generated from `xtrans[splitted_clusters]`?  We can't debug your problem with out a sample of `xtrans` or idea of how that gives transformed to produce the new `b`.

Comment: Could this be a floating-point precision issue? ie, the floats look the same when printed, but are actually not bitwise-identical? Try using np.round and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Attempting to perform equality tests on general floating point values is tricky.  Try `xtrans[i,:]==xtrans[j,:]` for any two rows that you think are identical.  Or look `xtrans[i,:]-xtrans[j,:]`.  The rows might not be as unique as you think.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn thank you, you are right. Now it works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by converting `list` to `set`.

```
 aList = [[ 0.157, -0.4778], [ 0.157, -0.4778],[-0.06156924,
 -0.21786049], [ 0.02, -0.35]]
```

1. Make a list of `tuples` from list of lists, otherwise you will [not be able to create set or dictionary from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532146/python-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type-list).
2. `Set` constructor will do rest for you

   `set([tuple(a) for a in aList])`

*Output:*

```
set([(-0.06156924, -0.21786049), (0.02, -0.35), (0.157, -0.4778)])
```

Comment: Then, of course, you can convert it back to two dimensional `list`

Comment: thank you for this idea, but I need to save the original indices of the array. For example in first code in my question the indices are in variable `idx`

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) implements functionality of this kind, in a manner similar to the solution you posted. But hopefully, its units tests will prove themselves useful, and things work as expected... Could you give it a try on your dataset, and see if it has the same problem?

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.unique(cluster)
# try this as well, to see if fp representation has something to do with it
npi.unique(cluster.round(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to finding unique rows in your numpy array would be

```
In [13]: uniq_vals, counts = np.unique(cluster, axis=0, return_counts=True)

In [14]: uniq_vals
Out[14]:
array([[-0.06156924, -0.21786049],
       [ 0.02      , -0.35      ],
       [ 0.157     , -0.4778    ]])

In [15]: counts
Out[15]: array([2, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

The option `return_counts` allows you to obtain the counts of unique rows.

This solution is explained in [Find unique rows in numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)