# Type error: unhashable type 'list' or 'numpy.ndarrary'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow placeholder defined as:

```
fs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(nn,  mm))
```

Further in the code, I want to feed it.
I will obtain a numpy array "features" with `shape = (nn, mm)` and I write:

```
feed_dict.update({fs, features})
```

However, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Unhashable type"numpy.ndarray"
```

Because I already could feed a list with `lenght = nn` to a placeholder with `shape = (nn,)`

So before feeding the numpy array to the placeholder, I wrote

```
features = features.tolist()   #to make them as a list, not numpy array!
```

again, I got a similar error:

```
TypeError: Unhashable type "list"
```

So, I was wondering how can I feed a 2d numpy array into a 2d tensorflow placeholder?

I also have checked that they all have `np.float32` and `tf.float32` datatypes!
I am using python3 with tensorflow version 1.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532146/python-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: It appears you are trying to use an array (or its list equivalent) as the key in a dictionary.  That doesn't sound like a realistic idea.  But if you must, you could turn the list into a tuple first.

Comment: @hpaulj one time I converted them to a list of tuples I got the quite same error. Another time I converted them to tuple of tuples I got "cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to sequence  ". Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a minor typo in your code. Where you wrote:

```
feed_dict.update({fs, features})
```

you should have written:

```
feed_dict.update({fs: features})
```

note the comma is replaced by a colon.

**What's going on**

In your code you accidentally tried to create a set containing `fs` and `features`, where what you meant to do was create a dictionary. In order to be placed in a set, a python object must implement a method called `__hash__`. Not all objects implement this method (for good reasons) and that includes lists and numpy arrays. So the reason you got the error message about an "unhashable type" is because you inadvertently tried to create a set containing `features`.

Comment: so you mean if I run the code with feed_dict.update({fs: features}) I will still get the same error?

Comment: @Kadaj13 `feed_dict.update({fs: features})` should be fine as the unhashable `features` is being used as a value. However, if you wanted to create a dictionary with `features` as a key (e.g. `{features: something}`) you would get the same error

Comment: @Kadaj13 the comments about dictionaries were an aside and not really directly answering your question any more, so I removed them to avoid any confusion.