# Attempt to invert a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to invert an initial dictionary of the following form:

```
Dict[str, list[str]] -> Dict[str,list[str]]

Example: INPUT: number_to_letter = {'1': ['A'], '2': ['B'], '3': ['B', 'D']}

OUTPUT expected: letter_to_number = {'A': ['1'], 'B': ['2', '3'], 'D': ['3']}
```

Code:

```
inverted = {}

for old_key in key_to_value:
    new_key = key_to_value[old_key]

    if not (new_key in inverted):
        inverted[new_key] = [old_key]
    #o/w append old_key to existing list
    else:
        inverted[new_key].append(old_key)
```

Which results in:

```
Expected = Dict[str,list[str]]

Error received: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532146/python-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do without a good example of your input and your output.  One interpretation of your problem might be:

```
key_to_value = {'2': ['A', 'B', 'C'], '3': ['B', 'C', 'D'], '4': ['C', 'D', 'E']}

inverted = {}

for old_key in key_to_value:
    new_keys = key_to_value[old_key]

    for new_key in new_keys:
        if new_key in inverted:
            inverted[new_key].append(old_key)
        else:
            inverted[new_key] = [old_key]

print(inverted)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
{'A': ['2'], 'B': ['2', '3'], 'C': ['2', '3', '4'], 'D': ['3', '4'], 'E': ['4']}
%
```

Comment: hi, please see edit made. I have included an example of the input and output. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! My apologies, at first I did not see your example output. This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you're currently attempting to use `new_key` as a dictionary key, try using `tuple(new_key)`  instead. A `tuple` is hashable, and therefore can be used as a dictionary key, whereas a `list` is not and cannot.