# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list` when setting value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to find the ten most frequent words from a text file.

```
def counting_word(script):
    outcomes_word = {}
    for i in script:
        i = i.lower().split()
        if i in outcomes_word:
                outcomes_word[i] += 1
        else:
                outcomes_word[i] = 1
    return outcomes_word
```

However when I typed the code as above, and use that function,
the result come as `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list`

Expected output :

[image]

if I need to upload any further information or txt.file, I will upload.

Please help me

Comment: Check out Counter: https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Why do you need to `split()` after `i.lower()`?

Comment: Please also read [ask]. Your title should summarize _the actual question you have_, not the overall goal of the project you're working on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python dictionary : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532146/python-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type-list) Please look for existing posts that answer your question _before you make one of your own!_ [Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because i (in your loop) is a list and it cannot be a key of dictionary.
You must split your list before the loop:

```
def counting_word(script):
    outcomes_word = {}
    l=script.lower().split()
    for i in l:
        if i in outcomes_word:
            outcomes_word[i] += 1
        else:
            outcomes_word[i] = 1
    return outcomes_word
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out,  when I put that into my python code. 'def counting_word(script):
    outcomes_word = {}
    l = script.lower().split()
    for i in l:
        if i in outcomes_word:
            outcomes_word[i] += 1
        else:
            outcomes_word[i] = 1
    return outcomes_word ' *** and when I typed 'counting_word(partb)', the result said that 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'.

Comment: Use your code and replace `outcomes_word[i]` with `outcomes_word[tuple(i)]`. Just a guess. Or better use counter.