# unhashable type: 'list' in python

Tags: python, types

I work with "memo" in recursion. The key of dict is a tuple (number, list) and recursion is a function of number, list and memo(dict)

I got an error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"
What is the reason for that?

I should find all the options for change. The number is the sum of the money and the list is the coins that I have (I have an infinity of them).
I tried to convert the list to tuple but then I cannot use method of list

```
 def find_num_changes_mem(n, lst, memo=None):
    lst.sort(reverse=True)
    if n<0:
        return 0
    if len(lst)==0:
        if n==0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    if memo==None:
        memo={}
    if lst[0]>n:
        return find_num_changes_mem(n, lst[1::],memo)
    else:
        if (n,lst) not in memo:
            memo[(n,lst)]=find_num_changes_mem(n-lst[0],lst,memo)+find_num_changes_mem(n,lst[1::],memo)
    return memo(n,lst)
    
print(find_num_changes_mem(5, [1,2,5,6], memo=None))
```

Comment: Because lists are unhashable and you are trying to store a structure which contains a list in a hash-based data structure. Wrapping an unhashable type in a tuple doesn't make it hashable. This is a reasonable enough question -- but your lack of a [mcve] is what is probably leading to the downvotes.

Comment: `{ [42]: "does not work" }`  => [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532146/python-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532146/python-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: Do not use lists as keys. Use hashable data types. We cannot help without [mre] that replicates your problem.

Comment: If I understand your question, you are using keys that look like `(1,[2,3])`. The solution could be as simple as using `(1,tuple([2,3]))`. Whether that is an optimal solution depends upon details which are unknown to us.

Comment: @JohnColeman I edited my post and added my problem

Comment: You could keep the input type a list but convert it to a tuple when you store it in `memo` and also when you check against `memo`.

Comment: I got "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable" @JohnColeman

`if (n,tuple(lst)) not in memo:
            memo[(n,tuple(lst))]=find_num_changes_mem(n-lst[0],lst,memo)+find_num_changes_mem(n,lst[1::],memo)
    return memo(n,tuple(lst))`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use tuples instead of lists, and replace the call to the list `sort` method by a call to the `sorted` function:

```
def find_num_changes_mem(n, lst, memo=None):
    lst = tuple(sorted(lst,reverse=True))
    if n<0:
        return 0
    if len(lst)==0:
        if n==0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    if memo==None:
        memo={}
    if lst[0]>n:
        return find_num_changes_mem(n, lst[1::],memo)
    else:
        if (n,lst) not in memo:
            memo[(n,lst)]=find_num_changes_mem(n-lst[0],lst,memo)+find_num_changes_mem(n,lst[1::],memo)
    return memo[(n,lst)]
    
print(find_num_changes_mem(5, (1,2,5,6), memo=None)) #prints 4
```

There was also a bug in `return memo(n,lst)` -- fixed by adding `[,]`